# Is there a way of telling what version of C++ you're running on Visual Studio on a Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio

I'm currently using visual studio to code c++ and I was wondering if there is a way to see what version of c++ (for example, c++11, 14, 17, 20) I'm using? I've tried typing gcc --version in my local terminal but all it tells me is the clang version.

Answer (score 0):

`Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1 Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)`

please pay attention to '4.2.1' after c++

Comment: That doesn't answer their question, and g++ on Macs are a relic that should not be used. As you note, it uses a much older Standard Library. clang++ (Apple's version11) supports most if not all of C++17.

Comment: You can do `std::cout << __cplusplus << "\n";` to see the which C++ standard is being adhered to by the compiler.  You can also use the [feature flags](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test) to see what core and library features are supported by your compiler, q.v. the example code.